# Why MR2 map task is running under 'yarn' user and not under user I ran hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run mapreduce job on MR2, Hadoop ver. 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0. Job has relative path to directory which has a lot of files to be compressed based on some criteria(not really necessary for this question). I'm running my job as following:

```
sudo -u my_user hadoop jar my_jar.jar com.example.Main
```

There is a folder on HDFS under path /user/my_user/ with files. But when I'm running my job I got following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/yarn/<path_from_job> does not exist.
```

I'm migrating this job from MR1 where this job is working correctly. My suggestion is this is happening due to YARN, because each container started under YARN user. In my job configuration I've tried to set `mapreduce.job.user.name="my_user"` but this didn't help.

I've found `${user.home}` usage in me Job configuration, but I don't know aware where it is set and is it possible to change this.

The only solution I found so far is to provide absolute path to folder. Is there any other way around, because I feel like this is not correct approach.

Thank you

Comment: does my_user have access to the folder?

Comment: I'm sorry, which folder? There is `/user/my_user/<path_from_job>` in HDFS and my_user has an access to this folder

Comment: is JAVA_HOME set correctly?